# Having trouble with navigating tables using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<div class ="table">
   <table class="stats">
      <td>Not this</td>
   </table>

   <table class="stats">
      <td>I want this</td>
   </table>
</div>


containers = page_soup.findAll("table", {"class":"stats"})
container = containers[0]
rows = container.findChildren(['td'])
```

i only get the first row of text but i want the 2nd row, it doesn't seem to be working properly... please help and thanks!

Comment: if you use `[0]` then you get ony first element. Use `[1]` to get second element. OR us `for`-loop to work with all elements  `for row in containers: cells = row.findAll('td')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `[0]` then you get only first element. To get second element use `[1]`

Or use `for`-loop to work with all elements

---

```
text = '''<div class ="table">
   <table class="stats">
      <td>Not this</td>
   </table>

   <table class="stats">
      <td>I want this</td>
   </table>
</div>'''


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')
containers = soup.findAll("table", {"class":"stats"})

container = containers[0]
rows = container.findChildren(['td'])
print('1st:', rows)

container = containers[1]
rows = container.findChildren(['td'])
print('2nd:', rows)

print('--- for-loop ---')
for container in containers:
    print(container.findChildren(['td']))
    print('-')
```

Result

```
1st: [<td>Not this</td>]
2nd: [<td>I want this</td>]
--- for-loop ---
[<td>Not this</td>]
-
[<td>I want this</td>]
-
```

Comment: you have in answer `containers[1]` to get second element.

Comment: thank you this really helped!!!! i was looking outside the box and not inside it ahahha